# Reading Facebook Statuses In Android

Tags: android, facebook

was just curious as to how I can go about reading Facebook status posts from a particular page through my Android application.

I looked into the Facebook API but that seems to be more related to making Facebook applications, which wasn't my intent.

If anyone can point me in the direction of a guide or link that will explain to me how to do this it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well the whole idea of the Facebook API is so that you can call their functions to give you access to Facebook content. If you want to incorporate them into your Android Application, try using their [Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/)